# ACPI Error, two finger scrolling failure, on ThinkPad E480

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, thinkpad, acpi, iwlwifi

A new [Lenovo ThinkPad E480 laptop](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-e480-type-20kn-20kq?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=E480%20(Type%2020KN%2C%2020KQ)%20Laptop%20(ThinkPad)) showed errors like `PCI Bus error severity=Corrected` among others. I searched for a solution and added the kernel boot parameter `pci=nomsi` permanently. The PCI error is solved, but there appear to be other errors as well. The following is the output of `dmesg -T -l err`:

```
[Do Okt  3 18:25:08 2019] **Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e**

[Do Okt  3 18:25:09 2019] **mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.**

[Do Okt  3 18:25:41 2019] **iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: pci_enable_msi failed - -22**

[Do Okt  3 18:25:41 2019] **ACPI Error: Field [TBF3] at bit offset/length 
262144/32768 exceeds size of target Buffer (262144 bits) (20170831/dsopcode-235)**

[Do Okt  3 18:25:41 2019] **ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed 
\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.GETB, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)**

[Do Okt  3 18:25:41 2019] **ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0.ATRM, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)**

[Do Okt  3 18:25:41 2019] **[drm:dc_create [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DC: Number of connectors is zero!**

[Do Okt  3 18:25:42 2019] **Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f**
```

I also had issues with keys of my keyboard that wouldn't react or get locked like the <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> and the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Today they functioned correctly but scrolling with two fingers didn't function even though it was set in the settings.

How may I troubleshoot to resolve these issues?